# Pandas resampling and variance doesn't keep timings

Tags: python, pandas, variance

I'm resampling some values in my dataframe, `df`, using `pandas` and the following code:

```
>> df['hour'] = f.Date.dt.hour
>> df = df.set_index('Date').resample('60T').mean().reset_index()
```

I correctly get the mean for each hour resampled by 60 mins, as follows:

```
>> print(df)
                  date       id       mean  hour
0  2017-02-09 14:00:00  12345.0  10.000000  14.0
1  2017-02-09 15:00:00  12345.0  10.166667  15.0
2  2017-02-09 16:00:00  12345.0  10.000000  16.0
3  2017-02-09 17:00:00  12345.0  11.000000  17.0
4  2017-02-09 18:00:00  12345.0   9.583333  18.0
5  2017-02-09 19:00:00  12345.0  11.333333  19.0
```

If I do the same code, on the same dataframe (prior to the above resampling), for the variance, the result is:

```
>> df = df.set_index('Date').resample('60T').var().reset_index()
>> print(df)
                  date   id        var  hour
0  2017-02-09 14:00:00  0.0  92.800000   0.0
1  2017-02-09 15:00:00  0.0  14.166667   0.0
2  2017-02-09 16:00:00  0.0   9.719697   0.0
3  2017-02-09 17:00:00  0.0  19.606061   0.0
4  2017-02-09 18:00:00  0.0   4.090909   0.0
5  2017-02-09 19:00:00  0.0   9.333333   0.0
```

Do you know why?

Edit:
using the .agg I correctly performed mean and median, but the variance keeps remaining nan. Why? Here's the code:

```
df = dataset.groupby(['ID',
pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='60T')])['Value'].agg(['mean', 'median',
'var']).reset_index()
```

And this is the result

```
,    ID,Date,mean,median,var
0,13834,2017-02-09 12:00:00,1.4749195494770717,1.4749195494770717,
1,13834,2017-02-09 16:00:00,4.424796460176991,4.424796460176991,
2,13834,2017-02-09 20:00:00,2.2418710493046774,2.2418710493046774,
3,13834,2017-02-10 00:00:00,2.6548672566371687,2.6548672566371687,
4,13834,2017-02-10 04:00:00,2.6548672566371683,2.6548672566371683,
5,13834,2017-02-10 08:00:00,0.5110619469026555,0.5110619469026555,
```

as you can see, variance is not even included in the output. How?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupBy.mean` and `GroupBy.var` will apply those calculations to all numeric columns.

In this case you define a numeric `'hour'` column which is the same value within a group. For `mean` this results in returning the single unique value as `mean([14, 14, 14, 14]) = 14`, for insance. However with var;  `var([14, 14, 14, 14]) = 0` which is why hour is 0 in every group with variance resampling.

You should likely supply a dictionary for aggregation to ensure you are using the correct function for each column:  `agg({'hour': 'first', ...})`

Comment: I'm not understanding how to use .agg.. let's say I have an ID column that needs to remain the same, and a Value columns on which I have to perform mean, median and variance, based on each hour for each ID. How do I use the .agg?

Comment: @thranduil90 You would want something like: `df.groupby(['id', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='60T')])['Value'].agg(['mean', 'median', 'var'])`. This creates groups for each `'id'` for every 60 minutes of the `'Date'` column then aggregates the column `'Value'` with mean median and variance.

Comment: thank you very much! But now, whenever I open the df, I find out that id and date are greyed out and not anymore in the columns, it seems like the index erased them out like in the screenshot attached: https://imgur.com/a/nfImzUm how do I fix this?

Comment: Basically, I need to maintain the ID and either the hour column or the date column

Comment: I fixed this, but in the edit there is a new problem

Comment: @thranduil90 The mean and the median are identical, which leads me to believe that your group size is 1. Variance isn’t defined for 1 data point.